# regex which accept positive integer and nothing

Tags: java, regex

hi I found on the Internet that this regexp accept positive number ^\d+$  and this accept nothing ^$
So no I wanna combine this two regexp but with no success. I try this (^\d+$)|(^$) but this didnt work. So help me with regexp which accept positive integer and nothing 
thx a lot

Comment: For which language are you writing a regex?

Comment: java: Pattern.compile(regexp)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simply do:

```
^\d*$
```

The `*` means: "zero or more times".

Since you've asked most questions with the Java tag, I'm assuming you're looking for a Java solution. Note that inside a string literal, the `\` needs to be escaped!

A demo:

```
class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] tests = {"-100", "", "2334", "0"};
    for(String t : tests) {
      System.out.println(t + " -> " + t.matches("\\d*"));
    }
  }
}
```

produces:

```
-100 -> false
 -> true
2334 -> true
0 -> true
```

Note that `matches(...)` already validates the entire input string, so there's no need to "anchor" it with `^` and `$`.

Beware that it would also return true for numbers that exceed `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and `Long.MAX_VALUE`. SO even if `matches(...)` returned true, `parseInt(...)` or `parseLong(...)` may throw an exception!

Comment: This does match multiple zeroes ("000") though. I used the somewhat less elegant regex `"0|[1-9][0-9]*"` to take care of that.

Answer (score 2):

Try `^[0-9]*$` . This one allows numbers and nothing.

Answer (score 2):

How about `^\d*$`? That would accept a sequence of digits (i.e. a positive integer) by itself in a line without whitespace or an empty line.